# Logging in spring with method interceptors

Tags: web-services, spring

I want to use method interceptors in spring 3 to accomplish logging in my app, so that I can trace which methods are called thru the app.

Is there a tutorial (or suggestion) on how to use method interceptors for logging in spring? 
It would seem like something that has been done numerous times, but I have not been able to find much data on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring reference has a [whole chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) on Spring AOP that serves as a very detailed guide for doing what you're looking for. Try that, and if you have some more specific questions, ask.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the answer such a question deserves. I did find that but I was hoping for some specific tutorial on how to accomplish exactly what I want. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Spring's **org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor** lets you achieve this out of the box.

You can customize the interceptor to your need to log argument and returned value of a method.

Example:-

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="loggingAdvisor"
        pointcut="execution(public * com.x.y.z.AbstractCommand.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
<bean id="loggingAdvisor"
    class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
    <property name="loggerName" value="logger-name" />
    <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])" />
    <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]" />
</bean>
```

[Spring Document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/CustomizableTraceInterceptor.html)

[Similiar SOF question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090/spring-standard-logging-aspect-interceptor)