# Spring: Standard Logging aspect (interceptor)

Tags: java, spring, logging, aspectj

I've found a lot of examples on how to create a custom aspect for logging using the Spring framework like [this](http://thoughtforge.net/2010/02/16/creating-a-logging-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/) or [this](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30799) but did not find standard/common Spring implementation for this situation and question. Are there any standard implementations of logging aspect from Spring or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes there are!

```
<bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor">
    <property name="enterMessage" value="Entering $[methodName]($[arguments])"/>
    <property name="exitMessage" value="Leaving $[methodName](): $[returnValue]"/>
</bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * BankAccountServlet.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

Check out the [CustomizableTraceInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/CustomizableTraceInterceptor.html) API, you can define separate enter/exit/exception messages with several placeholders:

> - `$[methodName]` - replaced with the name of the method being invoked
> - `$[targetClassName]` - replaced with the name of the class that is the target of the invocation
> - `$[targetClassShortName]` - replaced with the short name of the class that is the target of the invocation
> - `$[returnValue]` - replaced with the value returned by the invocation
> - `$[argumentTypes]` - replaced with a comma-separated list of the short class names of the method arguments
> - `$[arguments]` - replaced with a comma-separated list of the String representation of the method arguments
> - `$[exception]` - replaced with the String representation of any Throwable raised during the invocation
> - `$[invocationTime]` - replaced with the time, in milliseconds, taken by the method invocation

Comment: It is interesting, tomorrow will try it, Could you publish link where can I read about it? Thanks

Comment: @Tomasz - i tried this in Eclipse Virgo server from a OSGI bundle. it didn't print any log to the log file. i doubt its because of the weaving issue. but i dnt know exactly. can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sam: I am not very exprienced with OSGi, but I know this code snippet works in standard environment, sorry. Have you tried running it in a standalone application (single bundle running in JUnit test?)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - yes of course.this works fine in normal environments.i was still unable to figure out whats happening when it comes to OSGI..Thanks for your response tomasz..

Answer (score 1):

Here are the list of frameworks that do logging via AOP:

http://aspect4log.sf.net - does very nice looking logging via slf4j and @Log annotation. 
Can work via SpringAOP, and AspectJ. With AspectJ it works even for private methods and constructors and does not require a class to be a Spring Bean. 
Very easy to use, i was able to make it running with my project within 5 min.

http://loggifier.unkrig.de - does logging via java.util.logging, a bit too complex and not that well document but claims that it can instrument already compiled jar/war/ear files!

AbstractTraceInterceptor (from SpringAOP) and it's subclasses SimpleTraceInterceptor and CustomizableTraceInterceptor. Logging configuration is done separately from classes. Logs via commons-logging. Since it is designed for SpringAOP you have to work with Spring Beans (and only with Spring Beans public methods).