# Spring AOP Configuration (XML)

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop

I am experimenting with Spring AOP for the first time and get stuck in the XML configuration. I'm trying to get a mock version of AOP-based "logging" up and running, using a `MethodInterceptor` to wrap specific method calls and do some simple `System.out.println` statements before and after those method invocations. Simple stuff, right?

So my project has many classes, two of them are `Fizz` and `Buzz`. Fizz has a method named `foo()` and Buzz has a method named `wapap()`. Every time these methods are invoked at runtime, I want my `LoggingInterceptor` to execute its invoke() method around them:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor
{
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("About to call a special method.");
            Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Finished executing the special method.");
        }
    }
}
```

So I understand the concepts of advice (my interceptor impl), pointcuts (the methods that will have advice executed around them), and pointcut advisors (bindings between advice and pointcuts).

I'm just struggling tying it altogether in a simple XML config.

Here's what I have so far, but I know it's missing pointcut and pointcut advisor definitions, and possibly more.

```
<beans default-autowire="no" >
    <bean name="loggingInterceptor" class="org.me.myproject.aop.LoggingInterceptor"/>   
</beans>
```

**What am I missing here to make this specific to Fizz::foo() and Buzz::wapap() calls?**

Any nudges in the right direction are enormously appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="loggingInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * Fizz.foo(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="loggingInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * Buzz.wapap(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

You also need to add AOP namespace declaration in version appropriate to your framework:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        ">
```

Also consider using @AspectJ aspects and see this question: [Spring: Standard Logging aspect (interceptor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090).

Comment: Thanks Tomasz but it looks like those will call the logging interceptor advice for any Fizz or Buzz methods. I need it to specify foo() and wapap(). Also do I need to add an xmlns stuff to handle the new aop tags?

Comment: where is all this documented? I've been looking for some XML schema guides to the Spring AOP framework and can't find any!!! Also, what if I had an ExceptionInterceptor (implementing ThrowsAdvice) for when exceptions get thrown. How could I modify those pointcut strings to specify any Exception?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring 2.5+ you can use annotation to and create your advice and Pointcuts.

Create class with `@Aspect` annotation.

Create `@PointCut` for specific class and specific method and then create `@Around` advice.

You can read short tutorial how to do it here:

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/01/spring-aop-example-profiling-method-execution-time-tutorial/

It' very easy to implement.