# Can we log inside a method using AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-3

I want to log some statements in my method using AOP.

I am able to define the pointcuts, advice for method starting, ending, exception scenarios.

Can we log in between the method at some point (after method entry and before execution finishes?) I am using Spring 3.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring: Standard Logging aspect (interceptor)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090/spring-standard-logging-aspect-interceptor)

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: this is not a duplicate of this question, because the problem is how place some logstatement in the middle of the method. This theme is not discussed in the other question.

Comment: @java_enthu: My apologies, I misunderstood your question. Unfortunately I can't revert my close vote, but you have my +1 and an answer :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Spring is not capable of "looking into" your methods and modifying them. Technically AspectJ weaving can do this, but I would stay away from such approaches.

What you can do is to extract methods, which will not only allow you to provide some finer-grained logging, but you will also improve the overall code quality. However note that by default Spring can only intercept public (proxies) and protected methods (CGLIB).

Comment: Oh with Spring 3.x versions also not capable ?

Comment: From what I know, not. Again, Spring itself is not touching your methods, only intercepting calls. With real AspectJ weaving you **can** intercept variables access and private methods.

Comment: Why the downvote? If my answer is not correct please provide a better one and I will modestly delete this one :-).

Comment: @Thomas : by anyway can we mix AspectJ weaving with Spring AOP? and btw: i didn't downvote!!

Comment: Of course, you can use Aspectj LTW or CTW with Spring, for instance AspectJ can weave transaction support into your classes. You'll find plenty of resources over the Internet, I am planning to publish something about it today as well.

Comment: [Here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/10/spring-pitfalls-proxying.html) it is.