# generic bean factory in spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I want to implement a generic proxy for spring services (let's assume it does simple logging at the end and beginning of **method + execution** time of a method).

I'm using `spring` dependency injection and I want `spring` to create dynamic proxy mentioned above when injecting services. Is there any way to define **'global'** bean factory that is used when `spring` creates objects?

I'm using `@Autowired annotation` and I don't want to include each bean definition in **xml**, just trying to find generic solution.

Comment: I know this is not a direct response to the question, but have you considered using aspects for this job? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090/spring-standard-logging-aspect-interceptor

Comment: Unfortunately it's about something much more complicated than logging. I have to call some methods on decorated object.

Comment: Do you have a common interface on those objects?

Comment: yes I have common interface

Comment: That's doable as well with AOP, as you can access method parameters or the proxied objects themselves. Take a look here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: I will use AOP then, looks like something I can use. Thanks