# logging method's input params - is there alternative to the manual work?

Tags: java, logging, lombok

We are printing the input params of a method for debug purposes:

```
 public void findUser(User user, String abc, Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer rpp){
    log.debug("start findUser: user {}, startDate {}, endDate {}, abc{}, rpp {}", user, startDate, endDate, abc, rpp);
    ....
```

Writing such log messages is very annoying and error-prone.

Is there a way to achieve the same (or similar) log messages without all the manual work?

Comment: Lookup AOP Interceptors. For spring you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302090/spring-standard-logging-aspect-interceptor Similiar stuff can be done with CDI Interceptors.

Comment: Doesn't look *very annoying and error-prone* to me.

Comment: @akuzminykh well it is. If you do this for hundrets of methods it's easy to miss or misspell a parameter. And it's easy to forget to change the line when adding new parameters to the method.